# Apache Camel with Google Pubsub authentication via Json File

Tags: google-cloud-platform, apache-camel

I am looking to see if anyone has any samples of using a JSON File to authenticate to GCP instead of using the Environment Variable. I have not found anything that lets me override the default setup of Apache Camel.

Edit: Let me clarify, I am getting the JSON from a Vault and want to avoid creating a file. I have done it normally with a file.

Using Apache Camel 3.7 (along with the camel-pubsub dependency)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service account key option will be available with Camel 3.9.0

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-16273

Answer (score 0):

from("google-pubsub:" + cloudProperties.getProjectId() + ":" + cloudProperties.getSubscription() + "?"
+ "?concurrentConsumers=1&maxMessagesPerPoll=1&ackMode=AUTO&serviceAccountKey="+config.getAppCredentials())

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you [edit] your answer to offer an explanation of what you're doing and why it works? While you're at it, please also format your code using Markdown so that it's easier to read. Thank you.